# logical & on double in OpenCL?

Tags: if-statement, vector, opencl, bit-manipulation

I have two vectors: a `double4 *sum` and a `double4 *elem`. I'd like to do for each element in the vector, the following: if elem is finite, substract it from sum, otherwise, do nothing.

Currently, I have the following code:

```
   long4 finite = isfinite(elem[e].x);
   if (finite.x) sum.x-=elem[e].x;
   if (finite.y) sum.y-=elem[e].y;
   if (finite.z) sum.z-=elem[e].z;
   if (finite.w) sum.w-=elem[e].w;
```

However, that's a bunch of needless `if` statements. It could be replaced by simply `sum-=isfinite(elem[e])&elem[e];`, but it seems that & is not allowed on doubles. However, hardware-technically it should be possible, as & is just on bit level. Is there any way to mimic this behavior? How should I best do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution: apparently `union` can help here.

```
typedef struct {
    union {
        double4 asDouble;
        long4 asLong;
    };
} dubbel;
```

and then I can replace my if-statements by this non-branching code:

```
dubbel temp;
temp.asDouble = elem[e];
temp.asLong = temp.asLong & isfinite(temp.asDouble);
sum-=temp.asDouble;
```

Strange how this isn't provided as syntactic sugar by default, but hey, it works!

Edit: as pointed out by ScottD in the comments, an even shorter solution exists:

```
sum -= as_double4 (isfinite (elem[e]) & as_long4 (elem[e]));
```

Comment: Yes, that method works for me too (tested on AMD and Intel opencl). Here is another variation: `sum -= as_double4 (isfinite (elem[e]) & as_long4 (elem[e]));`

Comment: Ooooh nice! I didn't know those commands. I'll add them in the post.

Comment: By the way, do you happen to know anything about performance? I presume in the compiled code both conversions have zero cost, as they're just to put the compiler at ease?

Comment: I compared code generation using AMD HD 7950. The code for the union method and the as_ casting method is identical.